Different execution times for the same code
I'm working with the Texas Instruments (TI) RM57L843 microcontroller, where I'm observing the execution time of a for loop that performs matrix multiplication. I compiled the same code using TI's proprietary compiler (armcl) in Code Composer Studio and the GNU GCC ARM Toolchain v10.3. However, I obtained different execution times with each compiler.
Here is a simple piece of code I wrote that toggles PIN_OUT, a GIO pin on the microcontroller, while executing a for loop:
while (1) {
    gioSetBit(gioPORTB, PIN_OUT, 0);

    for (cntr = 0; cntr < 20; cntr++)
        MatMult_AxB(C, A, B, Rows, Cols, Rows, Cols);

    gioSetBit(gioPORTB, PIN_OUT, 1);

    for (cntr = 0; cntr < 20; cntr++)
        MatMult_AxB(C, A, B, Rows, Cols, Rows, Cols); 
}

I connected an oscilloscope to PIN_OUT of my microcontroller and observed the following execution times: with all optimizations disabled, the loop took 6.6ms with armcl and 17ms with GCC. With maximum optimization enabled, armcl achieved 2.8ms, while GCC achieved 8.2ms.
For maximum optimizations in armcl, I enabled the -O4 (Whole program optimizations) and -opt_for_speed=5 flags. For GCC, I enabled the -O3 flag.
Why is amrcl faster than GCC? And what can I do to optimize GCC to match armcl's performance?

Why would you expect both compilers to produce the same timing result?  armcl is based on LLVM/clang I believe.  You did not specify the clang version.

armcl is most likely optimized with parameters that are tuned for your system, such as specific CPU, memory sizes and speeds, neon, FPU, etc.  Also gcc v10.3 is fairly old and your TI clang could be more advance.  Finally, the compilers will do better on different code sets.  Clang is capable of some advanced higher level optimizations which may happen with the matrix multiply.

There are many factors here that we cannot see and cannot give an exact answer.  First off no reason to expect any two compilers or two versions of the same compiler to produce the same output.  Different output means different execution.  Beyond that there may be other settings that you have not described, and then something I demonstrate often is the same machine code can execute differently up to double digit percent or more, based simply on things like alignment of loops.

Higher optimization does not necessarily mean faster execution, fewer instructions can take much longer than more instructions.   There are a number of factors and if you really want to see what happened you need to dive into the compiler output.  (and/or work on what other differences there are.  llvm/clang will use the same abi so you can mix and match, use llvm to build the main object and link that in with the other toolchain for the rest of the binary and vice versa (to eliminate setup or buried stuff)
